# There is a way to get the directories separator of the current operating system using the os library?

Tags: python, os.path

I need to extract only the file name exploring a directories tree. For the moment I count the number of directories character separator so I can obtain the file name counting the character that are before the separator. Now I'm on windows but the code has to run in Linux too. For the moment I use this condition:

```
if file[n] == '\\':
   #do something
```

But on Linux this condition should be

```
if file[n] == '/':
   #do something
```

So I ask if there is a function that can provide me the direcotories separator of the current OS like:

```
if file[n] == os.directoriesSeparator():
   #do something
```

I check on the documentation of os library but I didn't find this kind of function.

Comment: Check `os.path.sep` or `os.sep`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path separator is available by using `os.path.sep`. For example:

```
import os

if file[n] == os.path.sep:
    # do something
```

It's also available via [`os.sep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.sep)

Answer (score 0):

```
  import os
  for root, dir, file in os.walk('Give Directory Path'):
     print file
```